# Ruby method to find a string within an array of strings

Tags: ruby

I've got an array of strings that looks like this:

```
[noindex,nofollow]
```

or
    ["index", "follow", "all"]

I'm calling these "tags_array." I've got a method that looks like this:

```
return true if self.tags_array.to_s.include? "index" and !self.tags_array.to_s.include? "noindex"
```

But I think there's a smarter way to run this code than to take the entire array and convert it to an string.

The problem is, sometimes the info comes in as a single element array and other times it comes in as an array of strings.

Any suggestions on the smartest way to do this?

Comment: FYI, if you are using methods like `include?` in a conditional statement with an `and` or `or` then you'll want to put the argument of `include?` in parentheses like `.include?("index")` or else you could throw off the condition.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that!  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You wouldn't have to convert your Array into a String since Array contains an `include?` method.

```
tags_array.include?("index") #=> returns true or false
```

However, like you said, sometimes the info comes in as an Array of a single String. If the single String element of that Array contains words that are always separated by a space then you could turn the String into an Array with the [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) method.

```
tags_array[0].split.include?("index") if tags_array.size == 1
```

Or if the words are always separated with commas:

```
tags_array[0].split(",").include?("index") if tags_array.size == 1
```

EDIT:

Or if you have no idea what they will be separated by but you know the words will only ever contain letters:

```
tags_array[0].split(/[^a-zA-Z]/).include?("index") if tags_array.size == 1
```

Comment: Aha, using the split method.  I really like that strategy.  Looks like the winner to me.  Thank you for your suggestion!